# Looking for a good 3D space vector class with dot product, cross product and other common operations

Tags: c++, vector, geometry

3D space vectors are widely used. But I cannot find a good small library dedicated to it. Any one have a good suggestion? The small library can have some basic geometry entities, such as triangles. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could always just utilize the OpenGL libraries :-p

Comment: @heckman OpenGL is a graphics API. It doesn't have any libraries vector math.

to the OP, I think this would suit your needs: http://glm.g-truc.net/

Comment: Perhaps Eigen http://eigen.tuxfamily.org?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try GLM. It is free and cross-platform. I have used it and once you get past the terrible documentation, it's fairly nice.

Answer (score 0):

You may also be interested in [Boost's uBLAS](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm)